# Background thread in IIS runs on multiple processes unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

OK - Ignore any bad practices you might see and bear with me, because the behavior I'm seeing makes no sense to me.

The setup:

- New, empty Asp.Net application (4.5.1 runtime, Server 2012 R2). One of
  many   applications that run in their own application pools, but all
  with the same   windows credentials.
- Add WebActivatorEx NuGet package. In the PreApplicationStart method,
  start a new thread and connect to a RabbitMQ Queue and listen for
  work.
- Application Pool is set to Always Running, Application has Preload
  turned off (Preload Enabled = False). Integrated pipeline.
- Each application pool is set to Maximum Worker Processes = 1.

Configured this way, when I look at the Rabbit server, I see one listener (identified by IP and port) for every w3wp.exe process running on my server. I can verify this by looking at the output of "netstat -ano" and comparing the PIDs to those in my task manager and the ports listed on the  Rabbit server.

Note that none of the other applications share any code with this new application.

Points to note:

- Turning Preload on fixes it (I get only one thread, tied to the correct process).
- Moving the code that starts the listener thread from the PreStart method into AppInitialize in the App_Code folder fixes it.
- The same thing appears to happen when running on Server 2008 R2 (it doesn't have preload so I can't fix it in IIS config).

The Question:

> How is it that code that is tied to one assembly can suddenly appear to be running threads in multiple processes that don't have that assembly loaded?

Comment: How many worker processes are configured/allowed for the application pool?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I meant to mention that. Each application pool is allowed only one process.